# Python list comprehension inside loop breaks Pycharm debugger?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to debug my code in Pycharm and running into unexpected behaviour when using the console while debugging.

When I run the below code normally, I get the expected output: ['A'] ['B'] ['C']

However, if I set a breakpoint after the code and copy/paste the 3 lines into the console while in debug mode, I get the output: ['C'] ['C'] ['C']

Why does it make a difference whether I run the code all the way through vs run it in the debug console?

**Code:**

```
for x in ['A','B','C']:
    myset = [x for _ in [1]]
    print(myset)
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What happens if inside the loop you only do `print(x)`?

Comment: (prev comment deleted) @HeapOverflow - If I only print(x), I get the expected output (I'm not sure how to add line breaks here): A B C

Comment: "if I set a breakpoint after the code" I wrote a line after your chunk of code and set the breakpoint there. I received ['A','B','C'] as expected. Is that different from what you did?

Comment: @Christina Zhou - once the code pauses at the breakpoint, go into the debugger console as shown in the screenshot. Copy/paste the three lines of code into the interactive editor and hit enter. Is your output different from that shown in the screenshot?

Comment: Which PyCharm version do you use? I believe this problem was already fixed in the recent version (2019.3.3 is the latest now).

Comment: @PavelKarateev - you're right, thanks. I was using 2019.1.3. I had to use the auto updater twice (it first updated me to 2019.1.4, then 2019.3.3), but now I get the expected output ['A'] ['B'] ['C']